# how to recieve the second activity intent on first activity

Tags: android, android-intent

i have created two activities,first activity comes and goes to second page i.e. to second activity,and second activity goes on first,what i wanted is that when 2 activity goes to first it has some data that to display in first activity.how can i do this please help.thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want data to go from Activity 1 to Activity 2, or from Activity 2 to activity 1?

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putInt("key", 1);

intent.putExtras(b);

startActivity(intent);

finish();
```

After it, we can get this data in a second activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

int value = b.getInt("key", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return result to 1st activity. Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)
.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned: Consider Activity1 calling `startActivityForResult`. In Activity 2 call `setResult` and immediately call `finish()`. Back in Activity1 capture the return values in `onActivityResult`.